# ASP.NET Core ConfigurationProvider from database

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft.extensions.configuration

I wonder if there is implemented ConfigurationProvider for ASP.NET Core which loads options from Database. EF or Dapper.
It's fairly easy to implement ourselves, but I wonder if there is ready solution, and if this really a good idea.

Comment: any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Comment: I don't like this project (it has one contributor and neglible download count) but yes, it correct, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use `EfConfigurationProvider`, you could directly use by installing through nuget package.

```
Install-Package EfConfigurationProvider -Version 0.2.1
```

More details about how to use it ,you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/jannikbuschke/ef-configuration-provider).

If this doesn't match your requirement, I suggest you could create the custom provider by yourself, like this [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20210226175439/https://blog.frandi.dev/2020/01/31/creating-custom-configuration-provider-that-reads-from-sql-server-database-for-asp-net-core-application/) shows.